# CakePHP Controller could not be found

Tags: php, cakephp, youtube

I am trying to create a simple Hello World program on cakephp before laying my hands on the popular forum application example but after going through the guidelines of one AndrewPerk on Youtube, I'm being told by the debugger to create "Create the class HellosController below in file: app\Controller\HellosController.php".

I am familiar with CakePHP conventions and principles, that is why I am surprised at this error. I will provide my codes and the file path below:

MODEL
cake/app/Model/Hello.php

```
<?
class Hello extends AppModel {
    var $name='Hello';
}
?>
```

CONTROLLER
cake/app/Controller/HellosController.php

```
<?
class HellosController extends AppController {
    var $name='Hellos';
    public function hello_world() {

    }
}
?>
```

VIEW
cake/app/View/Hellos/hello_world.ctp

```
<h3> Hello World </h3>
<p> This is just to test cakephp functionalities</p>
```

Based on the comments on the Youtube video, I was able to discover that many other people have the same error. I have tried to contact the author of the video but he isn't active on Twitter.

I don't see any error here, can someone please help?

Comment: What is the error you receive? What URL are you trying to access?

Comment: I try to access http://127.0.0.1/cake/Hellos and http://127.0.0.1/cake/Hellos/hello_world.ctp it gives me same error that there is no HellosController.

Comment: It would have been work. Please make sure that you are naming the same as you have mentioned ie HellosController.php

Comment: Are you sure your server has the php short tags turned on?

Comment: @Dave Tanx. That was the mistake I made. I have sorted it. It now works fine. Tanx everyone. This question can be closed as answered now.

Comment: If it WAS the short tags, I can write that as the answer for you to mark so we can call this resolved.

Comment: Yeah sure, sorry for the late replies. @Dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like everything is correct as far as the code is concerned.

If/when everything else seems correct but you're still having problems, start looking for the oddballs.  (The ones you rarely catch without having someone else look at your code).

**Common oddball problems:**

- If you're using PHP short tags, are they turned on on the server?
- Are there any spaces after you close your PHP tag? (shouldn't be closing PHP tags at all on class files)
- If working remotely, was the file uploaded (and into the correct directory)
- Does your file/folder have the correct permissions?

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was an accidental `namespace App\Controller\Admin;` instead of `namespace App\Controller;`.

Answer (score -1):

There must be an error because, You didn't provide the route for it. Unless it there will be no execution of the code to view.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33388145)